# How to run a public blockchain with one node and one full node

Tags: blockchain, hardforks, fantom

I want to create a personal blockchain for myself, for example, a fork of the Fantom network and public it

What should I do now?

Actually what code should I use, what changes should I make to change the name, chain id, rpc url, etc. and also what server should i buy and how should i put the blockchain on the server, i really need complete guidance, i will appreciate it if you can fully Guide me or introduce me if you know a course